# Relate or be related

Tags: active-vs-passive

How should I deal with 'relate' in this context?

> Basque is the language which is spoken in northwestern Spain and
>   southwestern France. It __________ (**not/relate**) to any other language
>   in the world.

Lots of my Russian colleagues say that active voice should be used there, while I disagree. How can a language relate? It can or cannot be related. So, 'isn't related' is the right answer.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

They aren't wrong. You can use "does not relate" there. See:
[American Heritage Dictionary "relate"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=relate)
v.intr.
1. To have connection, relation, or reference: *how education relates to income; a question relating to foreign policy.*

But, I don't see anything wrong with "is not related to".

Comment: Oh, thank you:) Is 'is not related to' passive voice of the verb 'relate' or is it some other grammar form?

Comment: The AH Dictionary shows that as an adjective:  adj. 1. Being connected; associated. I don't think it's a passive verb form there, since that would be based on a transitive verb form. That would be a reference to someone having "related" Basque to something else. Then, you might say "Basque has not been related to another language.", meaning no one has related it to another language.

Comment: Well, I see. I wonder, how do you distinguish an adjective and a passive form. Let's say 'connected' is it either or both?

Comment: See my edited comment. A passive form is based on a transitive form of the verb, and there should be a specifiable subject for that. Confer "is connected" in an adjective sense and "is connected by long cables" in a passive verb sense. I think there are cases where a distinction can't be made.

Answer (score 1):

'isn't related' tells us about what Basque 'is' or 'isn't'. 'doesn't relate' tells us about what it 'does' or 'doesn't do'. We more often talk about what a language 'is' (see the first sentence 'Basque is ...'). I would unhesitatingly say that 'isn't related' is the *better* answer, but, as Jack has explained, 'doesn't relate' is *possible*. To me, 'doesn't relate' is awkward here, but I can't explain why.

I would add that 'isn't related' here is not really a passive voice verb. Yes, it has the same form as a passive voice verb and it started as one, but it really is an adjective. We can test that by substituting an undoubted adjective like 'like': Basque isn't like any other language in the world.

Note that in terms of people, there is a big difference between 'Jack isn't related to his boss' and 'Jack doesn't relate to his boss'. In terms of languages, there probably isn't much difference.